# Integration Testing with Bunny Gem and RabbitMQ

Tags: rspec, rabbitmq, integration, bunny

I'm using the Bunny Gem with RabbitMQ on a project so that multiple applications can do RPC calls. I'm struggling to figure out a way to do integration testing with these calls. Sure I can mock and object and stub a method to return some fake data, but it sure would be nice to have something like the VCR gem with RabbitMQ. Any guidance on how best to test bunny?

Comment: I actually wrote a test jig using rspec but it is a little flaky and not satisfying.

Comment: Why bother doing integration testing across processes like this? Either you trust Bunny to work with RabbitMQ, or you don't. If you trust it, don't test it. If you don't trust it, don't use it.